# PHP Module not shown

Tags: php, server

I need php-cli module installed and working but when I run php -m this module is not listed although it's installed via yum. Both php-cli and php are listed and have the same version which are Version 5.4.16 release 36.3.el7_2. How can I make sure this module is correctly installed? phpinfo does not indicate the module is installed either.

Comment: If `php-cli` isn't installed then how are you checking via `php -m`?

Comment: Whats the module? Did you update your cli's php.ini file?

Comment: Your question does not really make sense, probably you made a typo... "php-cli" is not a module that is loaded _into_ php, so it will not be listed. But the fact that you can call the php cli executable proves that the package is installed and usable.

Comment: True. Thank you.